# Android can't parse JSON data

Tags: android, json

Here is my JSON :

```
{
 "columns": [
    "logoFileName",
    "logoFileName1",
    "companyEventIDUnique",
    "Date",
    "Event",
    "soldOut",
    "companyEventGroupDescription",
    "eventImageFileName",
    "teamsImagePath"
],
"rows": [
    [
        "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
        "SH11.png",
        14,
        "Monday, 13 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Sunrisers Hyderabad ",
        0,
        "RCB Home Games 2015",
        "rcb-srh.png",
        "images/upload/team/"
    ],
    [
        "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
        "MumbaiIndiansLogo.png",
        15,
        "Sunday, 19 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Mumbai Indians ",
        0,
        "RCB Home Games 2015",
        "rcb-mi.png",
        "images/upload/team/"
    ],
    [
        "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
        "ChennaiSuperKingsLogo11.png",
        16,
        "Wednesday, 22 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Chennai Super Kings ",
        0,
        "RCB Home Games 2015",
        "rcb-csk.png",
        "images/upload/team/"
    ],
    [
        "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
        "RajasthanRoyalsLogo11.png",
        17,
        "Wednesday, 29 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Rajasthan Royals ",
        0,
        "RCB Home Games 2015",
        "rcb-rr.png",
        "images/upload/team/"
    ],
    [
        "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
        "KKR_logo.png",
        18,
        "Saturday, 02 May 2015, 4:00PM",
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Kolkata Knight Riders ",
        0,
        "RCB Home Games 2015",
        "rcb-kkr.png",
        "images/upload/team/"
    ],
    [
        "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
        "KingsXIPunjabLogo11.png",
        19,
        "Wednesday, 06 May 2015, 8:00PM",
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Kings XI Punjab ",
        0,
        "RCB Home Games 2015",
        "rcb-kxip.png",
        "images/upload/team/"
    ],
    [
        "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
        "DelhiDaredevilsLogo12.png",
        20,
        "Sunday, 17 May 2015, 4:00PM",
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Delhi DareDevils ",
        0,
        "RCB Home Games 2015",
        "rcb-dd.png",
        "images/upload/team/"
    ]
]
 }
```

and i am not able to parse it.Please help me how can i parse it.

Comment: try to use Gson library.....

Comment: Can you please explain i never used GSON

Comment: what problem are you facing while parsing ?

Comment: You can simple use json parser for this ,Please explain your problem or show some code

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have? Have you tried using JSONObject and JSONArray to parse this data?

Comment: Ya but the problem is i want to arrange it properly

Comment: here is the code below                                                                             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
  JSONArray columns = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");
  JSONArray rowsWrapper = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");

Comment: It seems to be json parsing, which is not meaningful question......

Comment: This is the most stupid json format I hv ever seen. And @Ravi's answer should work for parsing.

Comment: he´s asking for somebody to program the thing... please, don´t answer!!

Comment: I use Json simple. There are lots of tutorials on how to use the library. https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ I would suggest reading up on Json and finding a library that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse it some thing like below code -

```
try{
        String result = "YOUR JSON DATA";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArrayColumns = json.getJSONArray("columns"); 
        for(int i=0;i<jArrayColumns.length();i++){
            String data = jArrayColumns.getString(i);
            Log.i("TAG", "JSON ARRAY"+data);
        }
        JSONArray jArrayRows = json.getJSONArray("rows"); 
        for(int i=0;i<jArrayRows.length();i++){
            JSONArray jRowItem = jArrayColumns.getJSONArray(i);
            for(int j=0;j<jRowItem.length();j++){
                String rowItem = jRowItem.getString(j);
            }
            Log.i("TAG", "JSON ARRAY rowItem"+rowItem);
        }


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How can i arrange it properly so that i can use the image and other events easily?

Comment: there are no key or flag in json response so you have to manage it by your self. or you can update json response from your webservice by passing data in key value pair.